# Yet to be received

Tags: passive-voice

We are expecting a letter, so if I write and say  "we are yet to be received the letter" is it correct?  Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

You are not being received, you are receiving (the letter) so you would not use a reflexive verb phrase.

The (lack of) reception is in the past so you would use either the past participle to show that the lack has occurred from the past up though the present:

> We have not yet received the letter.
>
> We have not received the letter yet. ("Yet" can go either place.)

Or the present perfect to show that the lack of reception is ongoing:

> We have yet to receive the letter. ("Yet" can only follow "have," *not* at the end of the sentence.